# Trigger a Donet console application from outside the container

Tags: .net-core, containers, console-application, pcf

We have a requirement to trigger(using a JCL command) a Dotnet Core Console application (hosted on a PCF container) from outside the container. What would be a good solution approach in this context.
One option we have is to convert the console app into a web api and host an API endpoint which can be called from external sources. Web api can then trigger a long running task (may be use something like Hangfire to handle the execution). Would like to hear if there are better approaches that can be used here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: executing command from outside container is not a good idea. it would be big "security breach".  Ideally you should be accepting request in some program and only after all validation you should execute command inside container.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry includes support for [running tasks](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html) which might be all you need. Additionally, [Steeltoe includes some functionality for building tasks into your application](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/management/tasks.html). There is a [Steeltoe Sample](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/main/Management/src/CloudFoundry#running-tasks) that can run EntityFramework migrations via cf runtask